# Complex Ellipse Equation Interpretation

Tags: complex-analysis

I could use some guidance on how to interpret the following equation. I know it describes an ellipse in the complex plane but I am unsure how to convert it into standard form so that I can clearly tell where the center is, what the foci are, the major/minor axes, etc.

The equation is:

$$
G = (1-2d)+2d\cos\theta +cj\sin\theta 
$$

where $G$, $c$, and $d$ are constants. I am most thrown off by the $1-2d$ term. I don't see how that fits but I am sure there must be a way re-write this so that it can be more clearly interpreted.

Comment: Shouldn't there be an $r$ in there somewhere?

Comment: No - This is how it is shown in the text. Also it indicates the major and minor axes are 2d and c, respectively and the ellipse is centered at ( (1-2d ) , 0j )

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me. If the only variable is $\theta$, then this is just an equation in a single variable, while an ellipse has to be described by an equation in two variables.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have really been scratching my head. But the text is clear and indicates what I just said in the previous comment.

Comment: OK, maybe this is the idea. I take it $j$ stands for $\sqrt{-1}$ – I'm more comfortable using $i$ for that. $\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ traces out the unit circle (in rectangular coordinates, $x^2+y^2=1$) as the parameter $\theta$ runs from zero to $2\pi$. $2d\cos\theta+ci\sin\theta$ traces out the ellipse $c^2x^2+4d^2y^2=4c^2d^2$ as $\theta$ etc., etc. $1-2d-G+2d\cos\theta+ci\sin\theta$ traces out the ellipse $c^2(x-1+2d+G)^2+4d^2y^2=4c^2d^2$. That's the only sense I can make out of it.

Comment: Any thoughts on my last comment?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP has lost interest.

Comment: Sorry - I have been busy with work and not able to digest what you said. But if you've lost patience please by all means. And thank you for suggestion on how they got it.